# How (in principle) does a web server receive an process an SMS message?

Tags: web-services, http, sms, sms-gateway, twilio

I want to understand in very simple steps/language what happens under the hood when

```
a) an sms is sent to a number like 40404

b) A web server receives an HTTP request with GET/POST parameters and executes an action.
```

i) What actually happens between `a)` and `b)`.

ii) What open source libraries (not cloud APIs) are there for handling that transition.

I know that there are APIs (like Twilio) etc that do this for me...but i want to know at a very high level what exactly is going on so I can actually learn this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

At a very high level, there is another mobile receiver (like your phone) on the other end. It receives the message and hands it to a computer. That computer has some program that understands the request (depending on implementation etc.), and can do any action it wants. For instance, it can send off a http request to a web server.

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest good resources for learning how the "mobile receiver" ..."hands off the message to a computer" ...and how to build this in practice?

Comment: Technically, you can interact with a GSM modem and use the AT commands to send messages. I'm biased (as an employee) but check out Twilio. When you have a number with us, the message comes in and we make a POST to a url you configure with all the message parameters.

Comment: Go through this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893562/send-sms-from-desktop-application/8034620#8034620) to understand how SMSs can be sent through applications using SMS gateways and what happens beneath the hood. Hope this helps.

Comment: @CaseySoftware Twilio was mentioned in the question, which was about how such systems work; perhaps as an employee you can comment on what hardware you use.

Comment: @j13r - I can't tell you because honestly, I don't know. Though I know that we have direct relationships with the carriers. It's really the only reliable way to make sure messages are sent/received. Even with the GSM modem solution, all it takes is the number being blocked and your operations are dead.