# Send Sms Using way2sms api

Tags: c#, asp.net, way2sms

I want to send SMS using **way2sms**. I have tried following code

**login.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
  public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["id"] = txtmobileno.Text;
        Session["pw"] = txtpw.Text;
        Response.Redirect("/send.aspx");
    }
  }
 }
```

**send.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WebApplication1
{
  public partial class send : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    string mbno, mseg, ckuser, ckpass;
    private HttpWebRequest req;
    private CookieContainer cookieCntr;
    private string strNewValue;
    public static string responseee;
    private HttpWebResponse response;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["id"] == null && Session["pw"] == null)
        {
            Server.Transfer("login.aspx");
        }
        connect();

        try
        {

            lblError.Text = "";
            lblError.Visible = false;
            if (!(IsPostBack))
            {
                btnSend.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return Validate('" + txtTo.ClientID + "','" + txtMessage.ClientID + "');");
                txtMessage.Attributes.Add("onchange", "TextChange('" + txtMessage.ClientID + "','" + lblLeft.ClientID + "');");
                txtMessage.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "TextChange('" + txtMessage.ClientID + "','" + lblLeft.ClientID + "');");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
            lblError.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            mbno = txtTo.Text;
            mseg = txtMessage.Text;

            sendSms(mbno, mseg);
            txtTo.Text = "";
            txtMessage.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
            lblError.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    public void connect()
    {
        ckuser = Session["id"].ToString();
        ckpass = Session["pw"].ToString();

        try
        {
            this.req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wwwd.way2sms.com/auth.cl");

            this.req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            this.req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            this.req.Method = "POST";
            this.req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            this.strNewValue = "username=" + ckuser + "&password=" + ckpass;
            this.req.ContentLength = this.strNewValue.Length;
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(this.req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            writer.Write(this.strNewValue);
            writer.Close();
            this.response = (HttpWebResponse)this.req.GetResponse();
            this.cookieCntr = this.req.CookieContainer;
            this.response.Close();
            this.req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wwwd.way2sms.com//jsp/InstantSMS.jsp?val=0");
            this.req.CookieContainer = this.cookieCntr;
            this.req.Method = "GET";
            this.response = (HttpWebResponse)this.req.GetResponse();
            responseee = new StreamReader(this.response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            int index = Regex.Match(responseee, "custf").Index;
            responseee = responseee.Substring(index, 0x12);
            responseee = responseee.Replace("\"", "").Replace(">", "").Trim();
            this.response.Close();

            pnlsend.Visible = true;
            lblErrormsg.Text = "connected";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrormsg.Text = "Error connecting to the server...";
            Session["error"] = "Error connecting to the server...";
            lblError.Text = ex.ToString();

            lblError.Text= ex.ToString();
            //Server.Transfer("login.aspx");
        }
    }
    public void sendSms(string mbno, string mseg)
    {
        if ((mbno != "") && (mseg != ""))
        {
            try
            {
                this.req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://wwwd.way2sms.com//FirstServletsms?custid=");
                this.req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                this.req.CookieContainer = this.cookieCntr;
                this.req.Method = "POST";
                this.req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                this.strNewValue = "custid=undefined&HiddenAction=instantsms&Action=" + responseee + "&login=&pass=&MobNo=" + this.mbno + "&textArea=" + this.mseg;

                string msg = this.mseg;
                string mbeno = this.mbno;

                this.req.ContentLength = this.strNewValue.Length;
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(this.req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
                writer.Write(this.strNewValue);
                writer.Close();
                this.response = (HttpWebResponse)this.req.GetResponse();

                this.response.Close();
                lblErrormsg.Text = "Message Sent..... " + mbeno + ": " + msg;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                lblErrormsg.Text = "Error Sending msg....check your connection...";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblErrormsg.Text = "Mob no or msg missing";
        }
    }

    protected void btnLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["id"] = null;
        Session["pw"] = null;
        Session["error"] = null;
        Server.Transfer("login.aspx");
    }

  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any changes in this code that I have to do? 
Please tell me any other way to **send sms** from `desktop` application or `web` application

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467905/sending-sms-from-asp-net-website

Comment: I have checked this website. But in my application if any one doesn't have account on way2sms or any other SMS site then using this application I provide facility to him to create account on way2sms site. once he create his account then he can use his login id and password for sending sms using this application.

Comment: "But it doesn't work" is NOT a good description of the problem your are facing. Please post any error/warning/exception messages your are getting.

Comment: yup, kindly show us the error message.

Comment: where is the API doc

Answer (score 2):

I dont know way2sms but the easiest SMS API I have found is http://cp.bulksmsportal.co.za/sms_default.aspx
Code is really simple as well

```
public static void sendSMS(string Recepient, string Message)
{
    //Recepient is the cellno in string format
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("http://www.mymobileapi.com/api5/http5.aspx?");
    sb.Append("Type=sendparam");
    sb.Append("&username={yourusername}");//add your username here
    sb.Append("&password={yourpassword}");//add your password here
    sb.AppendFormat("&numto={0}", Recepient);
    string message = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Message, ASCIIEncoding.ASCII);
    sb.AppendFormat("&data1={0}", message);

    try
    {
        ////Create the request and send data to the SMS Gateway Server by HTTP connection
        HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sb.ToString());
        //Get response from the SMS Gateway Server and read the answer
        HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader respStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream());
        string responseString = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        respStreamReader.Close();
        myResp.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: this is not addressing the issue at all

Comment: @Seabizkit then you clearly didn't read the entire question. "Please tell me any other way to send sms from desktop application or web application"

Comment: @Seabizkit Edited.

Comment: I agree - This is not a helpful solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used this : [GSM Communication Library (GSMComm)](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm)