# How to send sms from ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, sms, sms-gateway

I am developing an asp.net application in c# on which customer can order for some items. So my requirement is that **whenever any customer will create and order sucessfully then a SMS will be sent to customer's cell.** What I need to do for it ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to buy an SMS service.

Comment: Check this please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467905/sending-sms-from-asp-net-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to buy 3rd party services like http://www.twilio.com/

Comment: Every one is suggesting twilio here. Is it free? What are all the advantages of it. Is it same like using SMS gateways?

Comment: No it is not free. But it is easy to implement and offer features like bulk sms sending, schedule sms etc.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it. During development time also its cost? How should i get started? Can you add the steps like what is the necessary and the sample code?

Comment: Go to https://www.twilio.com/try-twilio and create an account. Get your account sid and auth token on this page https://www.twilio.com/user/account ,,, and check out the code on this page. https://www.twilio.com/user/account

Comment: It is expensive..Is there any other free or cheaper service?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/in .. it is like 100 SMS for 1$

Comment: https://www.nexmo.com , http://www.bulksms.com ,https://www.smsglobal.com