# how to send sms from asp.net website to the mobile?

Tags: asp.net, sms

I want to send SMS to the user from my asp.net website.. I surfed on the net about it but i couldn't get the proper answer. is there any built-in class provided by c#? How can I accomplish this task?

NOTE: I want to use this service most probably across the India.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending SMS from asp.net website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467905/sending-sms-from-asp-net-website)

Comment: Check out Twilio.  I've used them for SMS and they work great.