# How to receive SMS Text from mobile to Application?

Tags: c#-4.0, sms, twilio, sms-gateway

I developed sending SMS text to mobile using Twilio
[Sending SMS from asp.net website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467905/sending-sms-from-asp-net-website)
and it's easy, but my concern is how to receive SMS text from mobile?

Ex. Client SMS Text to

> Cell Phone #: 0923#####(server CP#)
>
> with message body: GET_REMAINING_STOCKS
>
> Then my Application will replied 20 Stock to the sender.

I checked the other thread but I can't find the exact answer. please help

Comment: Twilio evangelist here. Can you please expand your question a bit more?

Comment: it is done via help of call back url funtionality. As mentioned in the answer by philnash. Check the guide

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a Twilio developer evangelist, hello!

If you are looking to receive SMS messages in your asp.net app, then the best place to start is the [quickstart guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/hello-monkey). That should get you off the ground with receiving and responding to SMS messages in your application.

Let me know if this helps.